# How can i save into variable STATUS of the databricks job based on run_id

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, databricks

[image]

I need to save into variable in Databricks status of the job(IN PORGRESS/FAILED/SUCCEEDED).Databricks notebook is triggered via ADF.

I tried below code but its not working -

I get NONE

```py
import json
context_str = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson() 
context = json.loads(context_str)
run_status_obj = context.get('currentRunState', {})
run_status = run_status_obj.get('Status', None) if run_status_obj else None
print(run_status)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you trying to save the databricks job status? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: i have a table with logs in Databricks where I'm adding a pipeline status. Once the pipeline is triggered i add the following information to the table in Databricks - adf_pipeline name, adf_ID, adf_trigger type and status (In progress/succeeded/failed)

Comment: The only possible status by the time the job is actually executing your code would be `RUNNING`. If you write status at the very end of your job, you could say `SUCCEEDED`, and with a try/except clause you can catch exceptions and write them as `FAILED`.

Comment: Instead of writing the status from databricks, why not write the status from ADF instead? You can just add another activity to write a row with proper status depending on the outcome of your databricks activity.

Comment: @AnupamChand How can i fetch this status from ADF?

Comment: @Hanna Please see my response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the status within your ADF itself instead of changing your notebooks. Use look up activities to update your SQL.

1. Lookup activity to add a new row with some unique id, date and
   status = InProgress'.
2. Execute your ADB notebook
3. If successful,update your SQL row with 'Success'
4. If ADB notebook failed, update SQL row with 'Failed'.

Simplistic ADF flow will look like this.
[image]

When I executed the pipeline, I first had my new SQL row ('0002') added as below.
[image]

When my pipeline completed, my same row was as below with 'Failed' status.
[image]

I purposely failed my ADB notebook. But ofcourse if you test with a proper run notebook you will see your row get updated to 'Success'.

For the lookup activities, I use the below queries which you can use as a base and build upon.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ADBstatus] ([id],[date],[status]) VALUES ('0002', '2022-02-02', 'InProgress');
select 0 id;

UPDATE [dbo].[ADBstatus] SET [status] = 'Success' WHERE [id] = '0002';
select 0 id;

UPDATE [dbo].[ADBstatus] SET [status] = 'Failed' WHERE [id] = '0002';
select 0 id;
```

The additional select statement is to allow a dummy response from your SQL as LOOKUP activity mandates a response from your SQL.

If you prefer, you also use stored procedures instead of directly updating your SQL.
You can choose your own id convention. Can be the notebook name, linked service name, pipeline name etc.